# MultipartFile and nested object in a json to test post request in POSTMAN?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman

Wanted to test a post request in POSTMAN.

```java
public enum TimeUnit {

    HOURS("hours"),
    MINUTE("mins");

    private String value;

    public static TimeUnit get(String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(TimeUnit.values())
                     .filter(a -> Objects.equals(a.getValue(), text))
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

```java
public final class SchoolTimeTable {

  private Double value;
  private TimeUnit unit;
 
  public SchoolTimeTable (double value, TimeUnit unit) {
      this.value = value;
      this.unit=unit;
  }
}
```

```java
public class SchoolDto {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private MultipartFile profileImage;
    private MultipartFile[] galleryImages;
    private SchoolTimeTable openCloseTime;
 }
```

**Spring MVC** Controller

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/schoolInfo", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }) 
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveSchoolInfo( @Parameter(required = true, schema = @Schema(implementation = SchoolDto.class)) SchoolDto schoolDto) throws IOException, InterruptedException {  
   ...
}
```

I want to send **SchoolDto** (POSTMAN: body->raw->json) in post request to get desired result. But I am not able to create the json which supports SchoolTimeTable (Object) and MultipartFile types. I don't even know whether it is possible with JSON or not.
Note: Same could be achieved using body->form-data with key/value.

Please help.

Comment: Could you post your Spring Controller code ?

Comment: @PostMapping(value = "/schoolInfo", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveSchoolInfo(
            @Parameter(required = true, schema = @Schema(implementation = SchoolDto.class)) SchoolDto schoolDto) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

Here is the method signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not upload files within a `application/json` request, to do so you should use a `multipart/form-data` request. Your request may have three parts `profileImage`, `galleryImages` and `schoolInfo`.

Remove `profileImage` and `galleryImages` from `SchoolDto` class

Modify your method signature to support the multipart request

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/schoolInfo", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE) 
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveSchoolInfo(@RequestPart(value = "profileImage") MultipartFile profileImage, @RequestPart(value = "galleryImages") MultipartFile[] galleryImages, @RequestPart(value = "schoolInfo") SchoolDto schoolInfo) throws IOException, InterruptedException {  
   ...
}
```

In addtion you can implement a `@SpringBootTest` unit test using `RestDocumentationExtension` to check whether your code works and to produce a *curl* request sample that will help you to understand how to make a request to your endpoint

See [sb-mvc-multipart-demo](https://github.com/eljaiek/sb-mvc-multipart)

Comment: Yes I am also not getting proper solutions. 
Ok then there is no way to send multipartfiles in json along with other datatypes. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When I have used multipart/form-data I was using Spring Boot 2.0.x, Java 8 and with the same method = POST

There are points that you need to implement correctly. Maybe this can help you:

```
@RequestMapping(value = MEUVOUCHER_FILE, method = POST, consumes =  "multipart/form-data", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(code = CREATED)
public ObjectResponse<MEUVOUCHERFileRetrievalDto> createMEUVOUCHERFile(
    @RequestPart("MEUVOUCHERFile") MultipartFile MEUVOUCHERFile,
    @ApiParam(name = "metadata", value = "{ \"MEUVOUCHERTypeId\" : 0, \"relatedContentId\" : 0, \"expireDate\" : \"datetime\" }", required = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is true that by using "multipart/form-data" I can achieve it but I want to use raw json file in POSTMAN.