# How to pass object data type in form-data(Postman->post request url->body->form-data) in POSTMAN?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, postman

[MultipartFile and nested object in a json to test post request in POSTMAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66334428/multipartfile-and-nested-object-in-a-json-to-test-post-request-in-postman)
Extending this question where multipartfile and other data types are there in Dto and trying to test the post request in POSTMAN.

Passing **SchoolTimeTable** in form-data, please refer attached screenshot
[image]

Getting below error:
typeMismatch.schoolDto.openCloseTime,typeMismatch.openCloseTime,typeMismatch.com.vo.schoolInfo.SchoolTimeTable ,typeMismatch]

Please help me with proper way.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for content type then click the "meat ball menu"

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your effort. Actually I am looking for proper format or the possible way to send SchoolTimeTable (which I have mentioned in the example) object in the form-data so that my controller takes those input properly.

Comment: {
    "value": 10.0,
    "unit": {
        "value":"HOURS"
    }
}
I am providing it this way with content type "application/json". Getting same error.

Comment: try passing it as body>raw>json

Comment: instead of form data

Comment: With multipartfile type we can not send the json (body-> raw-> json).
Note: It will be possible if we use base64 to upload file.